# Bootstrap 4 .sticky-top changes to thead

Tags: html, css, electron, bootstrap-4

since a few days .sticky-top class does not work anymore on thead tags. Last Week it just worked perfectly, now I came back and tried few things on my App and it stopped working. Anyone got an idea why?

```
<thead class="sticky-top>
 ...
<thead>
```

That just worked perfectly. Now I cannot use it anymore. I tested it with just divs and for divs its still working, but I get an electron-dom error that I cannot spawn a div as a child of an table and i cannot spawn thead/th as child of a div.

Cheers, 
Puschek

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For everyone that is interessted in this problem:

Somehow you cannot sticky-top directly on thead (I just wonder why it worked 1 week ago...) so you have to stick the  elements to your `<thead>`. So just give every single `<th>` the `.sticky-top` class and it works without any problems.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I found out that `.sticky-top` does not work together with `.table-responsive`, in case you added that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483466/responsive-bootstrap-table-with-sticky-header) is a compromise solution

Answer (score 0):

Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge, but only after you scroll past it. The `.sticky-top` utility uses CSS’s `position: sticky`, which isn’t fully supported in all browsers.

Microsoft Edge and IE11 will render `position: sticky` as `position: relative`. As such, we wrap the styles in a `@supports` query, limiting the stickiness to only browsers that properly can render it.

`<div class="sticky-top">...</div>`

**Learn more about it**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#sticky-top

Comment: My applications runs in electron 1.7.5 with chromium 58 I assume. And it worked few days ago. I had to update boostrap due to some issues with other packages and after that I cannot use sticky-top on thead tags anymore!

Answer (score 0):

cheers
i had the same issue

check:
Few stuff to  corrected

1. make sure  tag or the div that wrap your navigation  is direct child 
   of body tag (this important)!
2. make sure the direct parent; (body) has no overflow property on it
   The rest is normal
   if you are using bootsrap 4 :-add sticky-top as usual or you can use 
   separate javascript tooo will work !!

http://blog.cloud66.com/position-sticky-problem/.