# Responsive Bootstrap Table with Sticky Header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a table. The only CSS I am adding to the standard Bootstrap library is the following to implement the sticky header:

```css
.table-sticky th {
  background: #fff;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 990;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive p-0 mt-2">
  <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover table-sticky">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1,001</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>dolor</td>
        <td>sit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1,002</td>
        <td>amet</td>
        <td>consectetur</td>
        <td>adipiscing</td>
        <td>elit</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The sticky header worked until I wrapped the table in the `div.table-responsive`. How do I allow these to co-exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to co-exist a `position: sticky` inside a `.table-responsive` without re-implementing the latter.

My solution ended up to be using `.table-responsive-sm` to refuse this trade-off when a responsive table is certainly not needed.

Comment: using .table-responsive-sm still doesn't allow me to use sticky header.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you need to code it yourself. Following JS will do the job:

```
var element = document.getElementById("fixed-thead");
var parentElement = element.parentElement;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    var coordinates = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (coordinates.y < 0) {
        element.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, ' + (-coordinates.y) + 'px, 0)';
    } else {
        element.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,0,0)';
    }
});
```

And in your table mark `thead` with `id="fixed-thead"` like this:

```
<thead id="fixed-thead">
```

I use `translate3d` to enable hardware acceleration to make it smoother. If user uses wheel to scroll scroll event is triggering very ofter I recommend using debouncing of scroll events.

In case your table has column with fixed with you can use setting `position: fixed` and `top: 0` instead of `translate3d`. But in case of a variable length `translate3d` is preferred.

In case you need to apply this code to multiple pages on page use following code:

```
function applyFixedHeader(element) {
var parentElement = element.parentElement;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        var coordinates = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (coordinates.y < 0) {
            element.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, ' + (-coordinates.y) + 'px, 0)';
        } else {
            element.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,0,0)';
        }
    });
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("{yourSelector, e.g. `.table-fixed` for the tables containing class `table-fixed`}");
elements.forEach(element => applyFixedHeader(element));
```

Comment: For all of those who copy and paste the code is missing ");" on the end x)

Comment: Is there any way to do this for *two* individual tables with their own fixed header on the same page? Like say if instead of "id", there was "class='fixed-thead'"

Comment: @peppy yes, you can select multiple elements via selector and then apply this code on all of them, Only thing you need to change, you need to iterate all selected elements and apply this code on them to make it work properly. I have changed the answer to cover this case too.

Answer (score 2):

without any additionnal CSS, you can fix table head by removing table-responsive from the div and adding class="bg-white sticky-top border-bottom" class to table  tag. Like this

```
<div class="table">
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="bg-white sticky-top border-bottom">FirstName</th>
     <th class="bg-white sticky-top border-bottom">LastName</th>
     <th class="bg-white sticky-top border-bottom">Class</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Cooker</td>
       <td>A1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>David</td>
       <td>Jeferson</td>
       <td>A2</td>
     </tr>
     ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Then the responsiveness goes away, right?

Comment: Yes. Try `class="table-responsive-sm"` to make the table scroll horizontally at small breakpoint