# Sticky Table Header on Bootstrap Responsive Table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a sticky table header. Using this CSS code it works perfectly on a standard table (it will remain sticky all the way to the bottom of the table.

```
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

However I need the table to be responsive for mobile devices (ability to scroll right). Unfortunately, it no longer works when I add the bootstrap table-responsive class (please see my https://jsfiddle.net/b8x16eht/)

How can I get it to function on both mobile and desktop (without setting fixed heights)

EDIT: Thanks to @UfguFugullu for pointing out another possible solution which is an improvement. It works well for desktop however it still does not work in responsive mode (when viewing from a smaller window). Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aqfjozrm/

```
.table-sticky th {
  background: #fff;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 990;
}
```

I managed to find a website which has gotten it to work on responsive tables as well as full width although it is not using bootstrap https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/new-zealand/auckland/hourly

I am starting to think that we need to add a javascript listener to offset the thead position from the body then update the top position style of the thead. Any js gurus here :)?

Comment: The responsive table class has an overflow, this will block the sticky position. And does this answer your question? [Responsive Bootstrap Table with Sticky Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483466/responsive-bootstrap-table-with-sticky-header)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this one out, I tried a number of other similar solutions (however I didn't see this one). It is definitely a step in the right direction as it works for desktop. The only problem is that it does not fix to the top when it is in responsive mode.